# Have you this knowledge?

Tags: word, knowledge, cipher

This is special puzzle, with no story. It should be very easy for people who know what is this:

> GgcuuUcaGuUgUauAuuUguUaa

The target is to find the word from that string.

> Formatted: Ggc uuU caG uUg Uau Auu Ugu Uaa

And, if you really want to crack this:

> Genetics...

Comment: A bit of feedback: I think the puzzle would have been a bit better without either of the hints.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in fact

> literally GENETICS, or possibly (see below) merely GENETIC.

To get it

> interpret triples of letters as codons in the RNA genetic code (it has to be RNA rather than DNA because it uses U rather than T). This gives a sequence of amino acids, which have both 3-letter and 1-letter abbreviations. Use the 3-letter ones, and use the capital letters in the base-string to indicate which letter to take from each. Thus:
>  Ggc -> Gly -> G
>  uuU -> phE -> E
>  caG -> glN -> N
>  uUg -> lEu -> E
>  Uau -> Tyr -> T
>  Auu -> Ile -> I
>  Ugu -> Cys -> C
>  Uaa -> Stop -> S

There's a bit of ambiguity here because

> we could take the final stop codon as (1) meaning to *stop* there (so we get GENETIC) or (2) to take the first letter of "STOP" (so we get GENETICS).